# How do I intercept packages in a Facebook application?

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, fiddler, packet-capture

I can not listen to HTTPS traffic in the Facebook application through Fiddler and Burp. SSL-Pinning is disabled through SLL Kill Switch 2 (other applications such as Twitter, Snapchat with SSL-Pinning are well-audible) and Mobile Assistant (for Burp). Web-version of Facebook is working fine, HTTPS-traffic is successfully listened.

I suspect that a possible problem lies in some authentication service that runs separately from the main application, as described in this article:

https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2013/08/20/intercepting-the-app-stores-traffic-on-ios/

For example, Twitter and Facebook use the `accountsd` service, which is responsible for integrating with these applications. But, firstly in the new versions of Kill Switch, this problem is solved, and secondly, I tried to perform the kill of this process manually, but does not work with Facebook.

How can I solve this problem of intercepting packets in a Facebook application?

Comment: Why do you need to intercept packets? Maybe there is some other way to do what you want

Comment: Have you managed to figure it out? I recon Facebook directly connects to the internet, w/o honoring proxy. VPN might be the way to go!